# How to get categories with navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 50 category and i wants to show 10 category on ist page and next 10 on next page and next 10 on next page and so on with navigation.
I am using this code.
But no any navigation creating.
but how to get navigation.

```
    $args = array(
                            'type'                     => 'post',
                            'child_of'                 => 0,
                            'parent'                   => '',
                            'orderby'                  => 'name',
                            'order'                    => 'ASC',
                            'hide_empty'               => 1,
                            'hierarchical'             => 1,
                            'exclude'                  => '',
                            'include'                  => '',
                            'number'                   => '0,10',
                            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                            'pad_counts'               => false 
                        );

                        $categories = get_categories($args);
                        // loop through the categries
                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
                            echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$category->name.'</a>'; // category link
                            echo "</br>";
                        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because you use the quotation marks in a wrong way.

try the following:

```
echo "<a href='".$cat_link."'>'".$category->name."'</a>";
```

or this:

```
echo "<a href=$cat_link>$category->name</a>";
```

Comment: my code is working fine and getting all categories. I need only navigation. thanx Could you help me for this..

Comment: if this doesn't solve your problem I guess the problem's somewhere else (your other code, class $category,...)